# How to hide a HTML element based on user role

Tags: user-roles

I have a login top bar I use for general users on the website front end and the admin like to use the wordpress admin bar. I am trying to find a way of hiding the login top bar for admin so they just use the wordpress admin bar (this is only enabled for admin). I would also like to change the CSS of the main container if admin is logged in.

I have been looking for code on Git hub and the web but can't find anything that has worked for me. Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this if you have jquery included in your page:

```
<?php
if ( is_super_admin() ) {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {    
        $("#IDofDivHoldingUserTopBar").css("display", "none"); // ID of user top bar
// ............................. OR     
        $(".ClassofDivHoldingUserTopBar").css("display", "none"); // class of user top bar
    });
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [current_user_can()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) function.

**Step:**

```
if( ! current_user_can('manage_sites')){
   // SHOW THE LOPGIN TOP BAR
}
```

Comment: This also works so I upvoted.